# Stopping running while loop if conditions are met

Tags: python, function, pynput

The code below is intended to print out the contents of arrays, until either the mouse (left click) is released, or the end of the array is reached. How would I stop the while loop in the function `logging_mouse`, once the mouse is released?

```
running = False
i = 0
delta_x=[1,2,3]
delta_y = [3,2,1]

def logging_mouse(running,i):
    while (running and i < len(delta_x)):
       print(delta_x[i],delta_y[i])
       i = i+1
    running = False

def on_click(*args):
    global running
    global i
    print(running)
    i = args[3]
    print(i)
    if args[-1]:
        if not running:
            running = True
            threading.Thread(target=logging_mouse(running,i)).start()
    else:
        running = False
        i = 0

with Listener(on_click=lambda event1,event2,event3,event4: on_click(event1,event2,event3,i,event4)) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to actually use the `args` to the `on_click` function... you can detect whether or not a button is pressed down or released, the signature for `on_click` should be `on_click(x,y,button,pressed)` where `x` and `y` represent the location of the mouse press, `button` says which button was pressed, and `pressed` is `True` if the button is down and `False` if it was released